# LocalStorage data get cleared after refreshed and click button

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am create a employee array object which consist of 4 arrays. I am trying to add new array in every 2 seconds after clicking on start button. I want it to end at 8th position. Everything is working fine here.

But if I refresh the page and click on the start button it get start from the beginning. Why clicking on start button is clearing the localStorage Data?

[demo URL](https://embed.plnkr.co/YQ9jUrs94pPFNCxcLVju/)

My code seem to be big but it is dong very small stuff.
Explaining code step by step.

1) First I create Employees array.

2) Push data into employees array.

3) localStorage SetItem

4) Get Item

5) onclick getitems to document on setinterval.

6) stop if the length of employee is 8

I hope it helps.

JS code to setItems to localstorage and get

```
function set_and_increase_localstorage_data(){
    employees.push(employees[3]);
    update_array();
    localStorage.setItem("empData", JSON.stringify(employees));
    var len = employees.length;
    console.log(len)
    if(len===8 || len>=8){
        window.clearInterval(setInt);
    }   

    getEmpdata();


}
function getEmpdata(){

    myJsonData = localStorage.getItem("empData");
    if(myJsonData){
        var myData = JSON.parse(myJsonData);
        var oblen = myData.length;
        console.log("JS object stored in localstorage: " + oblen);

        //setItem to localstorage
        if(myJsonData){
            // JSON data into javascript object
            var output = "<div class='wrapper'>";
            for(var i=4;i<myData.length;i++){
                output += "<div class='item'>" + myData[i].name + "</div>";
            }
            output += "</div>";
        }

        document.getElementById('json_data').innerHTML = output;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd wager that your script removes the values either when the page loads, when the button is clicked, or when the page unloads. It's also possible that you're just overwriting your previous values with the new ones.

Comment: please show relevant code extracts here, not on a third-party site

Comment: All I can say is that it "works as implemented". Please share the specific parts of the code where you are having trouble.

Comment: @Alnitak I was trying to do the same but it was throwing some error saying `"message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 81,
  "colno": 4`

Comment: @Santosh you don't need a running snippet - just show the bits that read and write to localStorage

Comment: I did update my question for that.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the page, the `employees` variable that you use to write into `localStorage` is always loaded with new data - you never read the data that's in local storage back into `employees`.

Comment: employees is a static array and I am pushing new array into employees. and then setItem to localstorage and then getItem to display in document. I think there is no reason to push the localstorage data into employees array again. While the localstorage is getting data from employees.

Comment: on reload, `employees` is always filled with new data, you don't read it back from localStorage

Comment: I guess employees don't get fill until I click the button. But When I refresh the page, the localstorage data is there but if I click button it clear and start from the beginning. To display the data in the document I am using localstorage only. for the top one.